# Javascript Binary to Decimal Calculator

Tags: javascript, binary

I have no idea why this code doesn't work, could anyone help:

```
toDecimal: function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var decimalValue = 0;
    for (var i = 7; i > 0; i--){
        var binaryValue = self.binaryArray[i];
        decimalValue += binaryValue * Math.pow(2, counter);
        counter++;
    }
    return decimalValue;
}
```

the code `self.binaryArray` is just an array of numbers (contains only 8, a byte, that's all i need to work with) something like this `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

**2nd'ly**

Can you provide a slicker way of doing the counter, for the life of me I can't figure out how to calculate the counter from the i value, which shouldn't be too difficult, simple maths really.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the variable "self" set?

Comment: Which is supposed to be the most significant bit: `binaryArray[0]` or `binaryArray[7]`? Also, your loop termination condition needs to be `i >= 0`; otherwise you never process the value at `binaryArray[0]`.

Comment: why you won't convert it with parseInt ? parseInt(binary, 2);

Comment: in the parent function, `module.exports = function () { return { toDecimal: function () {} }; };`

Comment: OK so where is the variable "self" declared and initialized?

Comment: @TedHopp that is probably the answer!!! 0 is the MSB

Comment: @DamianKrawczyk it will take the Array and covert it to decimal? or in each loop use `parseInt`?

Comment: `parseInt` would seem the way to go `parseInt([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1].join(''), 2) //15`

Comment: parseInt([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1].join(''),2)

Comment: You really didn't describe the way in which the code "doesn't work". Are you getting a wrong answer, or no answer? Errors in the console?

Comment: @Pointy have you tried running the code yet?

Comment: @No1_Melman well no, but I'm not really sure how to do that because I still don't know where/how "self" is defined. I think you've gotten a great answer from Mr. Hopp below so I'm OK with it if you are! :)

Comment: @Pointy I'm fine with it, i do point out that the `self.binaryArray` is just an array of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original loop never processes `binaryArray[0]`. As to a "slicker" way of doing things, assuming that `binaryArray[0]` is the most significant bit, I'd write your loop like this:

```
toDecimal: function () {
    var decimalValue = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        decimalValue = (decimalValue << 1) + self.binaryArray[i];
    }
    return decimalValue;
}
```

(The left shift is just a quick way of multiplying by 2.)

However, I like StephenH's suggestion:

```
toDecimal: function () {
    return parseInt(self.binaryArray.join(''), 2);
}
```

Comment: I forgot about parseInt! :)

Comment: @No1_Melman - The explicit loop will be a lot more efficient, so avoid the `join`/`parseInt` approach if performance is critical.

Comment: But must also remember that the bitwise operation will limit the size of bits to 32. Whereas the other method is limited to the max integer precision of Javascript (not important in this example) http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/NE87t/

Comment: @Xotic750 - You're right. However, one can simply replace `(decimalValue << 1)` with `2 * decimalValue` to address that problem.

Comment: Yes, just an observation and it changes the performance somewhat, though the loop is still faster http://jsperf.com/bits-vs-join/2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use JavaScript's built in [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function?

Syntax: parseInt(string, radix);

var n = parseInt("10001",2);

n = 17